# Issues with Os-prober

Tags: mount, partition, grub, garuda-linux

I booted Garuda Linux Gnome , an Arch based Linux distro from ventoy , after which I went into Gparted to delete the previous root and efi partitions from the previous installation.

To my surprise, I saw that the root btrfs partition was mounted at var/lib/os-prober/mount automatically at boot .

A few Google searches reveal os-prober to be something related to grub and boot entries.
I don't know what caused this unexpected behaviour.

Any thoughts ?

Is this a big issue?

Comment: Would this page ( https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/btrfs-root-partition-was-mounted-at-var-lib-os-prober-mount/32537 ) be related ? If yes then please update your question with the additional informations provided, if no then… provide the additional informations that went requested onto that page.

Comment: @MC68020 , That time I just simply unmounted it and continued to install , after that time I am unable to recreate the scenario. So what information is required, from the usb or my current installation?